# grafana 5.1.0 docker image permission issue

Tags: docker, permissions, centos7, mount, grafana

I’m trying to run a fresh new docker container of grafana 5.1.0 with bind mounts on a freshly installed default Centos7 minimal.

I'm working with the root account and doing exactly as the grafana documentation said, and i still have permission problems.

I'm starting the container like this:

```
docker run -ti -p 3000:3000 --entrypoint bash --volume "$PWD/data:/var/lib/grafana" grafana/grafana:5.1.0
```

inside the container shell, when i `"ls /var/lib/grafana"`, i get permission denied...

Any ideas of what can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**possible issues to check :**

- Docker version (latest stable is 18.05)
- storage driver (devicemapper vs overlay2)
- Selinux (check /var/log/audit/audit.log)